# use a pandas cell as a bucket and fill it up with other column values

Tags: python, pandas

## The Problem

Figure out how to generate a new row when the sum of two values from another DF is larger than the specified max capacity of that row, and storing the new values in the new row.

#### Background

A truck plans to go to two customers to deliver some packages, forming two routes to drive to deliver these packages (see `df_routes`). The truck has a max capacity of how many packages it can take per route (column `truck_max_capacity`). On the date of delivery, we get an update on how many packages the customer actually wanted (see `df_actuals`), which is different from our initial plan.

[image: inputs]

In our scenario here, the new values from df_actuals > df_planned. Therefore a new row for the new route needs to be created so we can send a truck to pick up these packages. So the wanted output should in theory look like the below `df_new_routes`.

[image: output]

#### My idea for a solution:

A function that could take:

- The sum of the plan for customer A and B in `DF_input_1`: 11+12 = 23
- The new actual values from `DF_input_2`: 14 + 13 = 27

  - Look at the `max_capacity` column says the max should be = 24:

    1. We take 14 from customer A and 10 from customer B
    2. Generate a new row for Customer B for 27-24 = `3` (the rest value)

## My challenges with this:

- I'm not sure how to complete the above steps so that a new row is generated with the rest value of `3`
- Am I overcomplicating this? Is there a way to more easily check if something is over a new sum value --> then create a new row with the "rest" value of `3` here?

##### Code to reproduce dataframes:

```
df_routes = pd.DataFrame({
                    'date':['2021-12-24','2021-12-25'],
                    'customer_1_id':['A', 'A'],                    
                    'customer_2_id':['B', 'B'],                    
                    'customer_1_planned_packages':[11, 10],                    
                    'customer_2_planned_packages':[12, 10],                    
                    'total_pallets':[23, 20],
                    'truck_max_capacity':[24, 24],
                    'cost_route':[120, 120] 
                     })

df_actuals = pd.DataFrame({
                    'date':['2021-12-24','2021-12-24','2021-12-25','2021-12-25'],
                    'shipper_id':['A', 'B','A', 'B'],
                    'actual_packages':[14, 13, 14, 13]
                     })

df_new_routes = pd.DataFrame({
                    'date':['2021-12-24','2021-12-24', '2021-12-25', '2021-12-25'],
                    'customer_1_id':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],                    
                    'customer_2_id':['B', np.nan, 'B', np.nan],
                    'customer_1_actual_packages':[14, 3, 14, 3],                    
                    'customer_2_actual_packages':[10, np.nan, 10, np.nan],                    
                    'total_pallets':[24, 3, 24, 3], #sum(S1_actual_pallets, S2 ... etc)
                    'truck_max_capacity':[24, 24, 24, 24], 
                    'cost_route':[120, 130, 120, 130]
                     })
```